# Tags should not be common for both favorite and ignored

Tags: feature-request, design

Once a tag is added to `favorites`, i don't think it should be allowed to be added as an ignored tag.It doesn't make sense to add a tag to `favorite` as well as `ignored`.

Comment: I agree completely; this seems like something quite fundamental that should be prevented. However it can get kind of funny to prevent, for example I have `sql-server*` as a favorite, but `sql-server-ce` as ignored. Do those conflict? I'm not sure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In cases such as that, the more specific preference (in this case, ignoring sql-server-ce) should override the general one where applicable.

Comment: @Saposhiente Right, and that's how it works now, I'm saying if the system were to actively prevent overlapping favorite and ignored tags, I'm not sure how the system would handle that scenario.

Comment: If you ignore a favorite, you get what you deserve.  No need to add code to check for this condition.

Comment: @Matthew That doesn't seem right to me - I think it's easy enough to hit tab and end up in the wrong text box and not notice, and it should easy enough to force me to pick one when it detects an exact duplicate (if it can do this for question titles...). The system already adjusts my silly logic in other cases, e.g. search for 'is:question is:answer tags' - what do you get? Not both, that's for sure.

Comment: @Aaron If you entered 'is:question is:answer' and got no results, would you look to see if there was something wrong with your query, or think that there were no questions or no answers?  I'd prefer that it did what you said, without adjustment for "silly logic".

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Personally, I'd rather see an error (conflicting search terms) than only questions. Some people don't like errors, so whatever, but in a lot of cases I'd prefer errors to silent behavior that isn't what I expected (and which I might not notice).